# wants to redirect to home page in angular js if user type wrong path and show correct URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If we edit the URL forcefully the web page shows the same content with different URL.
For example http://www.example.com/# and http://www.example.com/#/abc serves same content.
Wants to Redirect edited URL on Home page every time show correct path in URL.

```
.state('system.confirmation', {
            url: '/confirmation',
            templateUrl: 'tpls/views/system/confirmation/confirmation.html',
            controller: 'ConfirmationController',
            controllerAs:'confirmationController',

            }
```

Comment: Please provide more information i.e. what routing mechanism you're using, as well as code form your project. Otherwise, the community wouldn't be able to help you

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Your code doesn't have the mentioned URL `/abc`. Could you reword your question with actual values?

Comment: confirmation is my home url and /abc is arbitary url which is not defined in stateprovider i want every url with http://www.example.com/#/ to redirect to home if that url is not defined in state provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `otherswise()` function. Try adding this in your `config` function:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
```

This will make sure that all uncaught routes will be redirected to your base URL.

Comment: i have used that it redirect the page to the home but url remains the same.  i want url to be of home in browser when otherwise working

Comment: Well, you'll need to _define_ a home state and provide a template for it, for the content of the page to change. have you done that?

Comment: yes confirmation is my home page and template has been provided

Comment: Could you provide that code in your question as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, last) {
       console.log(event, next, last)// get all info, about current controller
       $scope.someFunction();
    });
```

You can do everything with this, before change any routes, this function will call, there you can check for something you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/index.html',
            controller  : 'indexController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/404.html',
            controller  : '404Controller'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/signup.html',
            controller  : 'signupController'
        })
        .when('/forgotPass', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/forgotPassword.html',
            controller  : 'forgotPassController'
        })              
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'views/site/login.html',
            controller  : 'loginController'
        }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });;
});


 App.controller('404Controller',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Page not found 404.';
}]);
```